# Spinner loading when form Model State is Invalid

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

Good day guys,

I have a spinner and works well. When I click submit button, it asks if user wants to submit or not and if OK press, it triggers the ActionMethod in the controller and the spinner rolls.

However, if the model state is invalid, the spinner keeps rolling and do not allow editing the form unless the page is refreshed. Any way to get this resolved. Below is code:

```
 $('#submitbtn').click(function () {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure to Submit Transaction?"); //confirm text
            if (x == true) {  //checking whether user clicked ok or cancel
            $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown)  
        } else {  //else if clicked cancel spinner is hidden
            $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
            return false //stops further process
        }
    });
```

I want it that if the modelstate is invalid, the spinner should stop rolling so that it will allow for correction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery to Check ModelState is Valid or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642629/jquery-to-check-modelstate-is-valid-or-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, validate your form first before taking any action. Validating form will check if all Model properties are correct:

```
$('#submitbtn').click(function () {
  if ($("#frmNameHere").valid()) {  //I added this

    var x = confirm("Are you sure to Submit Transaction?"); //confirm text
        if (x == true) {  //checking whether user clicked ok or cancel
        $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown)  
    } else {  //else if clicked cancel spinner is hidden
        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
        return false //stops further process
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I already got resolved with this kind of method. I am accepting because of someone else that will have the issue later